# Dancer2 app with PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, perl, dancer

I'm trying to integrate a small PostgreSQL database in my Dancer2....
After schema deployment I used this in my app.pm file to connect to the schema:

```
my $schema = My::Schema->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=mytestdb;host=localhost;port=5432;","test","test");
```

When I start my app I'm able to create a new user (which is inserted in the db) with this request:

```
post '/register' => sub {


    my $username = params->{username};
    my $fullname = params->{fullname};
    my $password = params->{password};
    warn "The pass is |$password|\n";


        my $saved_pass = &crypt_password($password);   



    $schema->resultset('User')->create({
        username => $username, 
        fullname => $fullname,
        password => $saved_pass,

    }); 

    redirect '/';

};
```

But when I attempt to log in using this:

```
post '/login' => sub {
    my $username  = params->{username};
    my $password  = params->{password}; 



     my $user = $schema->resultset('User')->search({ username => $username })->first;       




        my ($success, $realm) = authenticate_user(
            $username, $password
        );


        if ($success) {
            session logged_in_user => $success;
            session logged_in_user_realm => $realm;
            session user => $user;



        } else {
             authentication failed
        }       



};
```

My app dies with this error:
`DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::catch {...} (): DBI Connection failed: DBI connect('dbname=mytestdb','test',...) failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "test"`.

Comment: I think in the pg_hba file or whatever is its magic name there is noted which user can access via which interface the postgres database, so maybe additional settings must be made, to allow that new user access also via the interface chosen? Guessing, as I'm not a Dancer too ;-)

Comment: It worked after i added this to lines:      host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5 and local   all         all                               trust.

Comment: @DragosTrif: That isn't very clear for others hoping to get some help from this page. Where do these changes go? Please post an *answer* to your own question that describes your changes in context. You will also be able to accept your own answer

Answer (score 0):

I edited my pg_hba.conf file inside /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
by adding this lines :

```
    # IPv4 local connections:
    host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
    local   all         all                               trust
```

With these modifications my app logs in.